# C#, How to get the color of specific area inside an image

Tags: c#, image, pixel

How can I get the color of an area that has 5x5px inside an image.

```
int xPixel = 200; int yPixel = 100;                               
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(“C:/Users/admin/Desktop/image.png");  
Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(xPixel, yPixel, 5, 5); 
MessageBox.Show(pixelColor.Name);
```

This code does not work!.
[image]

Comment: What **specifically** does "does not work!" mean?

Comment: The C# code, throws errors.

Comment: What does the code do now? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: Not sure why you thought it would work. `Bitmap.GetPixel` takes the x and y coordinates only, and returns a single pixel. There's no overload that gets multiple pixels.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by that. Can we start by asking you to post code that actually compiles? For instance, if we disregard the odd path specification, there is no overload of `GetPixel` that takes 4 parameters. Either code compiles, or it does not. If it does, then you can complain that it does not do what you want, if it doesn't then you can't complain that it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: @gnud, So how can I add the dimension of 5x5 px.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I need to modify the code to make it works.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dimension of 5x5 px"? What does it mean to get the "color of an area"? Do you mean average color?

Comment: I want this code to got to 200x100 px coordinates and read the plain color within 5x5px area.

Comment: If the code "throws errors", then you have to post those errors.

Comment: I still don't understand what it means to read "plain color within 5x5px area", are you talking about average color? What if one pixel is red and another one is blue?

Comment: I have an image I want to specify an area (5x5 px) to read it color.

Comment: One pixel is one square = one colour. 5x5 px is 25 pixels = 25 potentially different colours. Which one of those pixels do you want the colour for?

Comment: @Danoram I need "Red" color. 25px will be plain color because my image is grids (5x5 each) with plain, it's not raster one.

Comment: @CrownFord If you can always assume that, then GetPixel will work fine, and _you don't need_ the 5x5 specification at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something this extension method to get dominant color in a region of an image in case they are not all the same

```
public static Color GetDominantColor(this Bitmap bitmap, int startX, int startY, int width, int height) {

    var maxWidth = bitmap.Width;
    var maxHeight = bitmap.Height;

    //TODO: validate the region being requested

    //Used for tally
    int r = 0;
    int g = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int totalPixels = 0;

    for (int x = startX; x < (startX + width); x++) {
        for (int y = startY; y < (startY + height); y++) {
            Color c = bitmap.GetPixel(x, y);

            r += Convert.ToInt32(c.R);
            g += Convert.ToInt32(c.G);
            b += Convert.ToInt32(c.B);

            totalPixels++;
        }
    }

    r /= totalPixels;
    g /= totalPixels;
    b /= totalPixels;

    Color color = Color.FromArgb(255, (byte)r, (byte)g, (byte)b);

    return color;
}
```

You can then use it like

```
Color pixelColor = myBitmap.GetDominantColor(xPixel, yPixel, 5, 5);
```

there is room for improvement, like using a `Point` and `Size`, or even a `Rectangle`

```
public static Color GetDominantColor(this Bitmap bitmap, Rectangle area) {
    return bitmap.GetDominantColor(area.X, area.Y, area.Width, area.Height);
}
```

but this should be enough to get started.

Comment: @CrownFord there is room for improvement, like using a `Point` and `Size`, or even a `Rectangle` but this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Ok, I will try the different ways.

Comment: Using `GetPixel` in a loop is strongly discouraged... there are much faster methods for that

Answer (score 1):

A solution that uses the actual drawing methods provided by `System.Drawing` to resize the given area to 1x1 and get its pixel value:

```
public static Color GetRectangleColor(Bitmap sourceBitmap, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
{
    using(Bitmap onePix = new Bitmap(1,1, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
    {
        using (Graphics pg = Graphics.FromImage(onePix)){
            pg.DrawImage(sourceBitmap,
                         new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1),
                         new Rectangle(x, y, width, height)),
                         GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        return onePix.GetPixel(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Though, if you are consistently working with squares of a uniform colour, I personally wouldn't bother. Just avoid any potential fades at the edges and you're fine:

```
public static Color GetRectangleCenterColor(Bitmap sourceBitmap, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height)
{
    return sourceBitmap.GetPixel(x + (width / 2), y + (height / 2));
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution, not sure why it's down-voted. Allow the tools to determine the color. The next logical step might be to return bool given a color and tolerance. ... something like `IsRegionNearColor(bitmap, rect, Color.Black, 0.5)`